# What happens if I don’t have enough space for the remaining resources from the season pass?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I don’t have the storage for my Dark Elixir from the clan pass. How do I burn Dark Elixir when I have Town Hall 7?

Answer (score 3):

I am a TH9 CoC player, and I got confused also the first time when I saw the overflowing Season Bank Loot. But the thing is that the EXTRA loot still stays. Like your Storage of Gold is 4,000,000 and you have 3,000,000. Your season bank is 5,000,000. So you then have 8,000,000 gold even if your storage is only half the cash. But when it becomes 7,999,999 gold, it's not becoming 8,000,000 again.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you make armies that are almost 100% made of dark elixir troops.

You can also upgrade your hero.

As well as upgrading your dark elixir storage.

Continue doing so until you have enough space for your dark elixir.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It will fill the empty storage, and any remaining that you earn will fill it again as space frees up. After that, you can't collect more Dark Elixir from the Drills.

If you aren't sure about how to spend the dark elixir, just rush your TH to Level 9 where you need a lot of dark elixirs to upgrade your heroes alone.